# About a step in the proof of $\sup(A+B) = \sup(A) + \sup(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

To prove $\sup(A+B) = \sup(A) + \sup(B)$, we show that $\sup(A+B) \geq \sup(A) + \sup(B)$ and $\sup(A+B) \leq \sup(A) + \sup(B)$

It's easy to show that $\sup(A) + \sup(B)$ is an upper bound for the set $A + B$. And so $\sup(A+B) \leq \sup (A) + \sup(B)$.

To show inequality in the other direction, one shows that given any $\epsilon > 0$ there exist $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ such that $x > \sup(A) - \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $y > \sup(A) - \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, which implies that $x + y > \sup(A) + \sup(B) - \epsilon$. As $\sup(A + B) \geq x + y$ for any $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, we have that $\sup(A+B) \geq x + y > \sup(A) + \sup(B) - \epsilon$.

I know that $\epsilon$ is arbitrary and can be arbitrarily small. But (algebraically) I don't see why "$\sup(A+B) \geq x + y > \sup(A) + \sup(B) - \epsilon$" $ \implies $ "$\sup(A+B) \geq \sup(A) + \sup(B)$".

Comment: Note, as one part of clearing your misunderstanding, that "$x+y$" in the middle of your inequalities plays absolutely no role. For the rest, there are already two answers that explain why what you wrote is sufficient.

Comment: @mathguy $x+y$ here links $sup(A+B)$ and $sup(A) + sup(B) - \epsilon$, and so I wouldn't say that $x + y$ "plays absolutely no role".

Comment: I meant, once you used them to link those two sides, you *no longer* need $x+y$ in the middle. Specifically in the last line of your post.

Comment: @mathguy You're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is related to proving that

> if $a > b - \epsilon$ for arbitrarily small positive $\epsilon$ then $a \ge b$.

We can prove this statement by contradiction. In particular, suppose $a<b$. For $\epsilon = (b-a)/2$, we have $b-\epsilon = (b+a)/2 >a$, which is a contradiction. Hence, $a \ge b$.

In your case, $a = \sup(A+B)$ and $b=\sup(A)+\sup(B)$.

Comment: Why is everybody so much in love with $\epsilon = (b-a)/2$? What is wrong with taking $\epsilon =(b-a)$?

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!

Comment: @mathguy: One could have the following statement instead: "if $a\geq b-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$, then $a\geq b$". In this case, your $\epsilon=b-a$ would not work. And of course, I have changed the statement.

Comment: @mathguy: "this is no reason to use". I don't see a reason against the use of it. There could be a reason using it: it makes the conclusion stronger, although this is not necessary.

Comment: @mathguy I guess given that we have $a > b - \epsilon$, it's "nicer" to obtain $a < b - \epsilon$ as a contradiction using $\epsilon = (b-a)/2$ than $a > a$ using $\epsilon = b - a$. But of course, $\epsilon = b - a$ does a give succinct contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $\sup(A+B)\geq\sup(A)+\sup(B)$ fails, then set $\epsilon=\sup(A)+\sup(B)-\sup(A+B)>0$ and put to the previous inequality about $\epsilon$ to see what happen.